# Firefox Cannot Open Profile Directory

Tags: firefox, profile

I just installed eOS 6. I was running Pop OS and backed up two Firefox profiles. I am trying to restore them.

I installed Firefox from flathub and pressing profile directory does not open a new window. When I try to manually navigate there, the window explorer says "This folder does not exist."

I tried rebooting and the problem remain. Any responses would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is flatpak install then Firefox profile should be located here:

/home/user/.var/app/

whereas "normally" it resides here:

/home/user/.mozilla/firefox

at least this is the case on my 5.7.1 elementary OS

In Firefox, if I select

Help>More Troubleshooting Information>about:profiles

I can open profile directory (but in my case it is not flatpak install, in case it makes difference?)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

For flatpaks, you need to enable the Home permission in system settings for Firefox.

Comment: Please add more details or a screenshot on how to do that.